# Slider of Myghtyslider chavroka to width auto scale

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

After adding css code for the width, the script does not display disappears when you refresh the browser.
In the "DOM" I noticed clientwidht 0px

After you press CTRL + browser appears everything, both clientWidth is an appropriate form
How do I add the width of a rigid script both appear correctly
or min-width, width: 100%, and adding value important to me does not scale to the full width

The question of how you deal with it?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   (function(){
    var windowWidth = self.innerWidth;
    var $example = $('#exampleone'),
    $frame = $('.frame', $example);
    $frame.mightySlider({
     // Navigation options
     navigation: {
      slideSize: '100%'
     }
    });
   })();
  });
```

```css
.mightyslider_modern_skin {
 position: relative;
 background: #000;
}

.mightyslider_modern_skin .mSFrame {
 -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
 perspective: 1000px;
 -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
 perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.mightyslider_modern_skin .mSFrame .mSSlideElement {

 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.mightyslider_modern_skin .mSFrame .mSSlideElement .mSSlide {
 overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
 transform: translateZ(0);
}

.mightyslider_modern_skin.horizontal .mSFrame .mSSlideElement .mSSlide {
 float: left;
}


.slider_description {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1000;
 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
   }
   .slider_description:hover {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.0);
    color: #FFF;
    border-color: #FFF;
   }
   
   /* Slider Styles */
   #exampleone {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
                                left: 0px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 868px;
                                min-width: 1380px;

   }
   #exampleone .frame {

                                 min-width: 1380px;
    height: 860px;

                                -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    perspective: 1000px;

    -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    perspective-origin: 50% 50%;

   }
   #exampleone .frame .slide_element {
    height: 100%;

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
   }
   #exampleone .frame .slide_element > div {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
                            
   }
   #exampleone .frame .mSCover img {
    max-width: none;
                                
   }

   /* Animated layers styles */
   .transparent {
    opacity: 0;
   }
   .bgImg {
    position: fixed;
                                top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 115%;
    background-position: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px) translateY(-7%);
    transform: translateZ(0px) translateY(-7%);
    z-index: 10;
   }
   .bgImg1 {
    background-image: url('http://www.wallpapermaiden.com/image/2016/06/17/hatsune-miku-undersea-vocaloid-twintail-anime-1268.png');
   }
   .bgImg2 {
    background-image: url('http://76.72.168.19/images/2015-11-28-788237.png');
   }
   .bgImg3 {
    background-image: url('https://archive-media.nyafuu.org/wg/image/1420/42/1420420990953.png');
   }
   .bgImg4 {
    background-image: url('http://www.fullhdwpp.com/wp-content/uploads/Dwarf-in-a-Hood-with-a-Magic-Weapon-42_www.FullHDWpp.com_.jpg');
   }
   .bande {
    background: url('wp-content/themes/onetone-pro/slider/assets/img/captions/bande.png') no-repeat 0 50%;
    height: 1110px;
    width: 632px;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px) translateX(-632px);
    transform: translateZ(0px) translateX(-632px);
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 120;
   }
   .line {
    background: url('wp-content/themes/onetone-pro/slider/assets/img/captions/line.png') no-repeat 0 50%;
    height: 1110px;
    width: 556px;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px) translateX(-773px);
    transform: translateZ(0px) translateX(-773px);
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 110;
   }
   .titres {
    left: 120px;
    bottom: 140px;
    color: #353535;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px) translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateZ(0px) translateX(-100%);
    z-index: 130;
   }
   .titres .titrePartie {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 38px;
    text-align: left;
   }
   .titrePartie > span {
    position: relative !important;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    background-color: rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.87);
    white-space: nowrap;
    letter-spacing: 6px;
   }
   .titres .titrePartie span.l1,
   .titres .titrePartie span.l2 {
    left: -50px;
   }
   .titrePartie > span.l1 {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 40px;
   }
   .titrePartie > span.l2 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 40px;
   }
   .titres .sousTitre {
    position: relative !important;
    left: -50px;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #353535;
    line-height: 28px;
    padding: 0 25px;
    background-color: #e4e3e5;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin-top: 1em;
   }

   @media screen and (max-width:959px) {
    .titres .titrePartie {
     top: 58px;
    }

    .titrePartie > span {
     padding: 7px 20px !important;
     letter-spacing: 3px !important;
     font-size: 25px !important;
     line-height: 35px !important;
    }
   }

   @media screen and (max-width:959px) {
    .bande {
     margin-left: -70px;
    }

    .line {
     margin-left: -70px;
    }

    .titres {
     left: 0px;
    }

    .titres .titrePartie {
     top: 58px;
    }

    .titrePartie > span {
     padding: 7px 20px !important;
     letter-spacing: 3px !important;
     font-size: 25px !important;
     line-height: 35px !important;
    }

    .titres .sousTitre {
     right: 60px;
    }
   }

   @media screen and (max-width:639px) {
    .bande {
     margin-left: -100px;
    }

    .line {
     margin-left: -140px;
    }

    .titres {
     width: 100%;
     padding-right: 80px;
    }

    .titres .titrePartie {
     top: 40px;
    }

    .titrePartie > span {
     padding: 5px 15px !important;
     letter-spacing: 2px !important;
     font-size: 20px !important;
     line-height: 30px !important;
     white-space: inherit !important;
    }
    
    .titres .titrePartie > span.l1 {
     margin-right: 7px;
    }
                   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div id="exampleone" class="mightyslider_modern_skin horizontal mightySlider">
<div class="frame mSFrame mSMouseDraggable" style="overflow: hidden;">
<div class="slide_element mSSlideElement" style="transform: translateZ(0px); width: 1380px;">
<div class="slide active mSSlide" msslideloaded="1" style="width: 1380px;">
<div class="mSCaption transparent bgImg bgImg1" style="text-align: center; position: absolute; opacity: 0; transform: translate(0%, 7%) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); z-index: 10;" data-mightyslider="loop: true, dontDelayOnRepeat: true" data-msanimation="{ speed: 1000, style: { y: 0, opacity: 1 } }, { style: { zIndex: 10 } }, { delay: 5000, speed: 1000, style: { y: '7%', opacity: 0 } }, { delay: 17000 }"></div>
<div class="mSCaption transparent bgImg bgImg2" data-mightyslider="loop: true, dontDelayOnRepeat: true" data-msanimation="{ delay: 6000, speed: 1000, style: { y: 0, opacity: 1 } }, { style: { zIndex: 10 } }, { delay: 5000, speed: 1000, style: { y: '7%', opacity: 0 } }, { delay: 17000 }" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0; transform: translate(0%, 7%) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); z-index: 10;"></div>
<div class="mSCaption transparent bgImg bgImg3" data-mightyslider="loop: true, dontDelayOnRepeat: true" data-msanimation="{ delay: 12000, speed: 1000, style: { y: 0, opacity: 1 } }, { style: { zIndex: 10 } }, { delay: 5000, speed: 1000, style: { y: '7%', opacity: 0 } }, { delay: 17000 }" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0; transform: translate(0%, 7%) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); z-index: 10;"></div>
<div class="mSCaption transparent bgImg bgImg4" data-mightyslider="loop: true, dontDelayOnRepeat: true" data-msanimation="{ delay: 18000, speed: 1000, style: { y: 0, opacity: 1 } }, { style: { zIndex: 10 } }, { delay: 5000, speed: 1000, style: { y: '7%', opacity: 0 } }, { delay: 17000 }" style="position: absolute; opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); z-index: 10;"></div>
<div class="mSCaption transparent bande" data-mightyslider="loop: true" data-msanimation="{ delay: 700, speed: 1000, style: { x: 0, opacity: 1 } }, { delay: 3300, speed: 1000, style: { x: -632, opacity: 0 } }" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0.990752; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);"></div>
<div class="mSCaption transparent line" data-mightyslider="loop: true" data-msanimation="{ delay: 600, speed: 1000, style: { x: 217, opacity: 1 } }, { delay: 3400, speed: 1000, style: { x: -773, opacity: 0 } }" style="position: absolute; opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(217px, 0px, 0px);"></div>
<div class="mSCaption titres" data-mightyslider="loop: true, dontDelayOnRepeat: true" data-msanimation="{ delay: 1000, style: { x: 0 } }, { delay: 5000, style: { x: '-100%' } }, { delay: 19000 }" style="position: absolute; transform: translate(-100%, 0%) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
<h1 class="titrePartie"><span class="mSCaption transparent l1" data-mightyslider="loop: true, dontDelayOnRepeat: true" data-msanimation="{ delay: 1000, speed: 1000, style: { opacity: 1, x: 50 } }, { delay: 3000, speed: 1000, style: { opacity: 0, x: -50 } }, { delay: 19000 }" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0; transform: translate3d(-50px, 0px, 0px);">Une agence marketing</span>
<span class="mSCaption transparent l2" data-mightyslider="loop: true, dontDelayOnRepeat: true" data-msanimation="{ delay: 1100, speed: 1000, style: { opacity: 1, x: 50 } }, { delay: 3000, speed: 1000, style: { opacity: 0, x: -50 } }, { delay: 19000 }" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0; transform: translate3d(-50px, 0px, 0px);">indépendante et 100% intégrée</span></h1>
<a class="mSCaption transparent sousTitre" href="#" data-mightyslider="loop: true, dontDelayOnRepeat: true" data-msanimation="{ delay: 1200, speed: 1000, style: { opacity: 1, x: 50 } }, { delay: 3000, speed: 1000, style: { opacity: 0, x: -50 } }, { delay: 19000 }" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0; transform: translate3d(-50px, 0px, 0px);">Des expertises complémentaires pour une réponse globale</a>

</div>
<div class="mSCaption titres" data-mightyslider="loop: true, dontDelayOnRepeat: true" data-msanimation="{ delay: 7000, style: { x: 0 } }, { delay: 5000, style: { x: '-100%' } }, { delay: 19000 }" style="position: absolute; transform: translate(-100%, 0%) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
<h1 class="titrePartie"><span class="mSCaption transparent l1" data-mightyslider="loop: true, dontDelayOnRepeat: true" data-msanimation="{ delay: 7000, speed: 1000, style: { opacity: 1, x: 50 } }, { delay: 3000, speed: 1000, style: { opacity: 0, x: -50 } }, { delay: 19000 }" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0; transform: translate3d(-50px, 0px, 0px);">Une agence marketing</span>
<span class="mSCaption transparent l2" data-mightyslider="loop: true, dontDelayOnRepeat: true" data-msanimation="{ delay: 7100, speed: 1000, style: { opacity: 1, x: 50 } }, { delay: 3000, speed: 1000, style: { opacity: 0, x: -50 } }, { delay: 19000 }" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0; transform: translate3d(-50px, 0px, 0px);">experte du BtoB</span></h1>
<a class="mSCaption transparent sousTitre" href="#" data-mightyslider="loop: true, dontDelayOnRepeat: true" data-msanimation="{ delay: 7200, speed: 1000, style: { opacity: 1, x: 50 } }, { delay: 3000, speed: 1000, style: { opacity: 0, x: -50 } }, { delay: 19000 }" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0; transform: translate3d(-50px, 0px, 0px);">Le marketing au service des professionnels</a>

</div>
<div class="mSCaption titres" data-mightyslider="loop: true, dontDelayOnRepeat: true" data-msanimation="{ delay: 13000, style: { x: 0 } }, { delay: 5000, style: { x: '-100%' } }, { delay: 19000 }" style="position: absolute; transform: translate(-100%, 0%) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
<h1 class="titrePartie"><span class="mSCaption transparent l1" data-mightyslider="loop: true, dontDelayOnRepeat: true" data-msanimation="{ delay: 13000, speed: 1000, style: { opacity: 1, x: 50 } }, { delay: 3000, speed: 1000, style: { opacity: 0, x: -50 } }, { delay: 19000 }" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0; transform: translate3d(-50px, 0px, 0px);">Nativement</span>
<span class="mSCaption transparent l2" data-mightyslider="loop: true, dontDelayOnRepeat: true" data-msanimation="{ delay: 13100, speed: 1000, style: { opacity: 1, x: 50 } }, { delay: 3000, speed: 1000, style: { opacity: 0, x: -50 } }, { delay: 19000 }" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0; transform: translate3d(-50px, 0px, 0px);">data</span></h1>
<a class="mSCaption transparent sousTitre" href="#" data-mightyslider="loop: true, dontDelayOnRepeat: true" data-msanimation="{ delay: 13200, speed: 1000, style: { opacity: 1, x: 50 } }, { delay: 3000, speed: 1000, style: { opacity: 0, x: -50 } }, { delay: 19000 }" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0; transform: translate3d(-50px, 0px, 0px);">L'intelligence des données client au coeur de la stratégie</a>

</div>
<div class="mSCaption titres" data-mightyslider="loop: true, dontDelayOnRepeat: true" data-msanimation="{ delay: 19000, style: { x: 0 } }, { delay: 5000, style: { x: '-100%' } }, { delay: 19000 }" style="position: absolute; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
<h1 class="titrePartie"><span class="mSCaption transparent l1" data-mightyslider="loop: true, dontDelayOnRepeat: true" data-msanimation="{ delay: 19000, speed: 1000, style: { opacity: 1, x: 50 } }, { delay: 3000, speed: 1000, style: { opacity: 0, x: -50 } }, { delay: 19000 }" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0.860608; transform: translate3d(43.0304px, 0px, 0px);">Expertise de</span>
<span class="mSCaption transparent l2" data-mightyslider="loop: true, dontDelayOnRepeat: true" data-msanimation="{ delay: 19100, speed: 1000, style: { opacity: 1, x: 50 } }, { delay: 3000, speed: 1000, style: { opacity: 0, x: -50 } }, { delay: 19000 }" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0.860608; transform: translate3d(43.0304px, 0px, 0px);">l'ultra-personnalisation</span></h1>
<a class="mSCaption transparent sousTitre" href="#" data-mightyslider="loop: true, dontDelayOnRepeat: true" data-msanimation="{ delay: 19100, speed: 1000, style: { opacity: 1, x: 50 } }, { delay: 3000, speed: 1000, style: { opacity: 0, x: -50 } }, { delay: 19000 }" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0.860608; transform: translate3d(43.0304px, 0px, 0px);">L'individualisation de votre stratégie marketing et commerciale</a>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Slider test :
http://melodiatest.byethost22.com

Login to Wordpress: tester
Password to Login: tester

Comment: Main achievements assumption is such that when changing resolution or resizing windows automatically dopasowywało width

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out as once someone had a similar problem, I suggest it does not need to dump the css that may interfere.
fix it:

```css
#exampleone {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
                                left: 0px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 668px;
               
                                width: 100%;
   }
   #exampleone .frame {

                                 width: 100%;
    height: 660px;

                                -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    perspective: 1000px;

    -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    perspective-origin: 50% 50%;

   }
   #exampleone .frame .slide_element {
    height: 100%;
                                width: 100% !important;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
   }
   #exampleone .frame .slide_element > div {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
                            
   }
   #exampleone .frame .mSCover img {
    max-width: none;
                                
   }
```

```html
<div id="exampleone" class="">
  
/* class null its important*/
```